# Vue.js lazy loading loads chunk files two times

Tags: vue.js, components, lazy-loading

I have a vue.js router implemented and if I run npm run build it correctly creates separate files for every component. But if I run npm run serve and then open the page all components files are loaded immediately not lazy. If I click on the link to component it loads the components file again. I don't understand why it is not lazy. Look at the screenshot. There are contact.js (which should be chunk) loaded two times. First on refresh second on link click.

[image]

Comment: it's called prefetching. `vue-cli` 3 does this by default: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#prefetch Regarding the chunk being loaded twice, I suggest that you build in production mode and then check the actual response of both the duplicate requests. I think the second time, the chunk only gets loaded from browser cache and does not make a network request

Comment: Yes it seems like a prefetch. Where I can find something about vue.config.js?

Comment: Here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#working-with-webpack

Comment: Make an acceptable answer. It works fine with vue.config.js. Everything is ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's called prefetching. `vue-cli 3` does this by default as [explained here](http://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#prefetch).
Regarding the chunk being loaded twice, I suggest that you build in production mode and then check the actual response of both the duplicate requests. I think the second time, the chunk only gets loaded from browser cache and does not make a network request